# How can I call a task from within a Python route that should continue after sending the response?

Tags: python, web-scraping, async-await, streaming, python-asyncio

I'm using Falcon as a quick and easy way to set up some routes and run Twint, which scrapes data about followers and tweets from Twitter in a quick and dirty way that is just a lot easier than dealing with their api. However some of the data returned will be really large - somebody with 10,000 followers, for example, will output a lot of JSON from Twint. So in my front end app I plan to call the route, and I think easier than trying to deal with building a streaming api from Python (not easy from what I've seen!) - I wanted to just call the Twint function to begin gatherig the data from the route, then send the response with just a file name rather than the actual data. Then I think I can reasonably manage client side with Oboe or something like that.

My Python code uses asyncio, which may be part of my problem - but the fact is I'm beyond hacking this in Python as I'm a Javascript'r who has only mildly dabbled in Python over the years!

Here is my code - which results in the route hanging until all of the data is complete, THEN sending the json w/ the file name back to the browser. Not exactly what I wanted. If anybody has a better idea I'd be happy to hear it, or if you can see my obvious error that would be great too.

```
import os

import json, falcon
import twint
import requests
import random
import string
import asyncio

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

def randomString(stringLength=5):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))

async def get_tweeps(filename):
    # Configure
    c = twint.Config()
    c.Username = "mspanish"
    c.Store_json = True
    c.Output = f"{filename}"
    c.User_full = True
    twint.run.Followers(c)
    print('Hello ...') 
    
class GetFollowers:
    def on_get(self, req, resp, name):
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        filename = f"followers_{name}_{randomString()}.json"
        asyncio.run(main(filename))
        resp.media = {'twint': filename}
        resp.complete = True
        
api = falcon.API()
api.add_route('/followers/{name}', GetFollowers())
```

Comment: While you do use asyncio, its use is hidden behind the blocking `asyncio.run(...)` entry point, so it blocks `on_get`. To get the benefit of asyncio, you should look into using an async-native server, such as [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#run-a-simple-web-server).

Comment: I switched to aiohttp and you are right, it works beautifully. But now deployng is somewhat of a nightmare, there are no good working examples and the FAQ on deplying on the main docs does not shed light on what one would need to do on Heroku, AWS, etc. Have you ever deployed an aiohttp site? I am wishing I had tried Flask instead, so much support for it!